# jQuery - .on('click') not working on <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I've been tasked with making a website using Wordpress and on the homepage there's a slider that if you click on the buttons below, it's displays another image, simple right? Well, I've got the slider and I've got the buttons, I've added the jQuery and it doesn't want to work.

I first tried making the buttons actually buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="hideshow-healthcare">Healthcare</button>
```

and that worked fine when I used this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#hideshow-healthcare').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('#healthcare').show();
    };
};
```

So after having it working like that, I moved on to making the buttons in to li's instead so that I could follow the design. Upon doing this, the slider no longer works. I've tried mulitple different things including adding the ID to everything in the li to see if that would work, and sadly not. I did some research and tried to change

```
    jQuery('#hideshow-healthcare').on('click', function() {
```

to

```
    jQuery('li#hideshow-healthcare').on('click', function() {
```

but still, no luck. I was hoping someone would be able to provide a solution to this problem.

Also, this is the li code I'm currently using:

```
<li><a id="hideshow-healthcare"><h5>HEALTHCARE</h5> Lighting to create a feeling of well being</a></li>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your first working attempt is no different than the answers you claim work for you... you haven't got any different results. I wonder if it's cause you are not using `e.preventDefault();` in the click event? Actually, you don't have a `href` so prob don't need to prevent default

Comment: I'm not quite sure what has changed between my first attempt as the only thing different I can see is the space between the li and the ID, but it appears to be working :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add space after li element to find its descendants `#hideshow-healthcare`. It should be

```
 jQuery('li #hideshow-healthcare').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked... I feel stupid now, something so simple hahaha. I'll mark your answer as the right one once I'm able to!

Comment: @musefan: i was about to mention that. But thought if OP needs it then why not...

Comment: yeah, he seems to be happy with it... but this will still add the event to the `a` tag right? I think maybe the OP doesn't realize that

Answer (score 3):

**`#hideshow-healthcare` is child of li**. Use descendant selector in jquery

```
jQuery('li a#hideshow-healthcare').on('click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault(); // prevents default action 
       // your code 
});
```

**Id be unique in html** you just straightly write with id

```
jQuery('#hideshow-healthcare').on('click', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault(); // prevents default action 
           // your code 
 });
```